# How do I detect the deletion of a queue and then re-declare it

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

My application will create a queue which is `auto-delete` at startup. The application environment may lose its network and rabbitmq server will delete queue, therefore, after the network is restored, the listener will continue to report errors: the queue cannot be found. How do I detect this and recreate the queue?

How about using `cachingConnectionFactory.setCloseExceptionLogger`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a `Queue` `@Bean` and a `RabbitAdmin` `@Bean`, the admin will redeclare the queue each time a connection is opened. It registers itself as a `ConnetionListener` with the connection factory.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#broker-configuration).

Comment: Another way is to handle `BrokerEvent` on the matter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#broker-events. The `queue.deleted` routing key should be considered for such a situation.

Comment: Instead of declaring the queue in this application, this application will call a HTTP interface to create the queue(the other application creates the queue), and the application will initialize the message listener after receiving the response of the successful creation.

Comment: It's a little strange to use an auto-delete queue for such a scenario - even if you redeclare it, you risk message loss during the period between deletion and re-creation. As long as you register a `Queue` bean with the application context, the admin will automatically re-declare it for you when the connection is re-established.

Comment: As you suggested, I got the name of the queue after calling the interface and add a ```Queue```  ```Bean``` to put into the Spring container, which seems to work.